# If Ker $T\subset$ Ker $T^*$ then $\exists C>0$ such that $\langle Tx,x\rangle_{X'\times X}\geq -C\|Tx\|_{X}^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, dual-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $T:X\rightarrow X'$, where $X'$ denotes the dual space of $X$. Let $T^*:X''\rightarrow X'$ be the adjoint of $T$. I am asked to show that **if** Ker $T\subset$ Ker $T^*$ (in the sense of the usual embedding from $X$ to $X''$) and range $T$ is closed, **then** there exists a constant $C>0$ such that

$\forall x\in X: \langle Tx,x\rangle_{X'\times X}\geq -C\|Tx\|_{X'}^2$

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Edit: fixed the type-o (range of $T^*$).

My attempt:
Sadly, I don't have much of an idea on how to approach the problem  (beyond really basic ideas like: if there exists $x_n$ such that $\|Tx_n\|=1$ and $\langle Tx_n,x_n\rangle < n$). I was able to prove that the inequality implies the inclusion between kernels by contradiction, showing $\langle Tz,x\rangle=0$ via parametrization $z=tz_0$ (for suitable $z_0$) and letting $t\rightarrow 0$. But this method is too indirect to try to somehow apply to address the other implication.

Comment: $Tx \in X'$ so RHS is $\|Tx\|_{X\color{red}'}^2$?

Comment: Observe that the conditions imply that the mapping $(Tx,Ty)\mapsto \langle Tx,\,y\rangle$ is a well defined bilinear form on ${\rm range}\,T$. It might be useful, though I can't see exactly how..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**sketch of a proof**:

Your idea with $\|Tx_n\|=1$ and $\langle Tx_n,x_n\rangle < -n$ was already a good idea.

Here is an idea how to continue based on the open mapping theorem.
Let $Y$ denote the (closed) range of $T$.
If we consider $T:X\to Y$, then $T$ is surjective and we can apply the open mapping theorem.
Then we can find $y_n\in X$ such that $Ty_n=Tx_n$ but such that $y_n$ is bounded by a constant.

Since $T(y_n-x_n)=0$, we also have $T^*(y_n-x_n)=0$ or $T^*y_n=T^*x_n$.
This can be used to show
$\langle Tx_n,x_n\rangle =\langle Ty_n,y_n\rangle$.
Since $y_n$ is bounded, this is a contradiction to
the inequality $\langle Tx_n,x_n\rangle < -n$.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I know comments are not meant for expressing gratitude, but your proof helped me understand better quite a few related concepts.